# Separating a user entered ASCII string by a separator character

Tags: ascii, delimiter

I have a list of some strings entered by users. I want to concatenate them into a single string by separating them by a specific character. That character should be:

- not reserved by the machine for string actions (example: no `\0`)
- not be used normally by humans (example: no `\n` or `\t` or jus `A`, `B`, ...)

To guarantee that a normal user would not use it when noting a normal message, and it is not reserved by the computer. Do you know any suitable character?

Comment: that probably depends on the domain of you application and the type of messages you are expecting. Something like `$§|;:_\/~#`. But I'd suggest using a more strucutred data format

Comment: If you control what's separating the strings & writing them, you can use whatever normal, printable separator character you want. Just have the writer escape the separator character when it occurs in the source text, and also escape the escape character when it occurs. You should really do that no matter what character you use, if you're not going to use a more-structured scheme.